# Making a jar as a maven repository in web

Tags: maven-2, maven

I have a jar in hand (dont have source or project making the jar) and also i dont have have a maven repository.

I like to publish it on web so it acts as a repository.

i tried this with a maven artiefect. but is it possible to do with my .jar file ?

i want users to access it as a dependent jar.

Any one help me how to publish my jar as a maven repository on my website.

Comment: Tell us a little more abut your web site, for example, can it run Java?

Answer (score 1):

If one of the following scenarios is true:

- you can install arbitrary programs on your web host, or
- your web host has Java installed and you are can run arbitrary Java programs on it, or
- your web host runs a servlet container like *Tomcat*, *Jetty*, *GlassFish*, or *Resin*

.. then you could use [**Arifactory**](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php) with a simple configuration to be a public repository for any and all of your artifacts.

See [Arifactory User Guide](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+User+Guide).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest installing [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), an open source web service that acts as a local repository for your artifacts.  This is practically a must-have for Maven development as it gives you a reliable means of deploying your artifacts and retrieving them later.

Once installed, set up the permissions to make whatever artifacts you'd like available to the outside world.  You can even directly link to the Nexus repository from a more conventional website.

Comment: Say, i have a xmz.jar. i like this to be available into a repository. can i add this into Nexus ? note: i dont have sourcecode or have a project to directly deploy.

Comment: Yep, you can add third party artifacts to Nexus through a web UI.  See http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading-artifacts.html.